# elsa-workflows Integration with .net framework

Tags: elsa-workflows

I am planning to use elsa workflow in my application. I have below clarifications.

1. I need to integrate the elsa workflow to my .net framework
   application (v4.5) is it possible.
2. Even i have copied code from elsa core project to my .net framework application will it work?.
3. I have cloned Elsa.Core project from git. And i have set Elsa.Dashboard.Web as startup project. Build and samples are working fine but dashboards are showing error it didn't able to load js and css files referenced

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to wait for 2.0 to be finished so that you can talk to Elsa via the APIs rather than embedding in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Elsa.Dashboard.Web dont support bootstrap.
if you use from bootstrap in your project your dashboard will not be show and you have to develop yourself dashboard and for this purpose you can use:

```
<elsa-workflow-definition-editor-screen id="wf" server-url="ServerUrl" workflow-definition-id="DefinationId" monaco-lib-path="/js/monaco-editor/min" />
```

for editor.
Note that you must change "ServerUrl" with your address, for example "http://localhost:59952"
and change "DefinationId" with your workflow defination id for example "6df200330adb4ee093db73c3f5d464c6"